# Doing expression for project relation in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, expression

I've build an relation between two vectorlayers. Now i want to write an expression for the relation. The standard expression which is given, is to filter features from the first field. Did anybody have an idea how to change this with python?

Code example:

```py
rel = QgsRelation()
rel.setReferencingLayer(str(map1.id()))
rel.setReferencedLayer(str(map2.id()))
rel.addFieldPair('map1field','map2field')
rel.setId('relation')
rel.setName('to_do_list')
QgsProject.instance().relationManager().addRelation(rel)
```